# How to get data of specific month sql

Tags: sql, join, group-by

I have a student table that contain admission_date and student_status column, i want to get total admission of each month of a specific year, while admission_date column type is DateTime. i.e

```
**Month**      **Total_Admission**
Jan-2016             90
Feb-2016             70
Mar-2016             109
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with the below query.

```
SELECT replace(right(convert(varchar, admission_date, 106), 8), ' ', '-') Month,COUNT(*) TotalAdmissions
FROM yourTable
WHERE YEAR(admission_date) = 2016
GROUP BY replace(right(convert(varchar, admission_date, 106), 8), ' ', '-')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `extract(year_month...` to retrieve statistics per month. Something like this:

```
SELECT
    extract(year_month FROM date(admission_date)) month,
    count(*) total_admission
FROM your_table;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS admission_total
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY MONTH(admission_date)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH,admission_date),3)+'-2016' as MonthNumber,COUNT(*) TotalAdmissions
FROM TableName
WHERE YEAR(admission_date) = 2016
GROUP BY LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH,admission_date),3)+'-2016'
```

Comment: its getting the admissions of each date, but i want each month

Comment: Column 'Student.admission_date' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: yes that i have tried earlier, but i could get it like jan-2016

Comment: @UsfNoor Updated Ans